# Regd : Implementing Geofencing in Android Application

Tags: android, google-maps, geofencing

I am trying to implement Geo Fencing in an Android application.
I want to create a service which is in the form of notification which triggers when the user has exited or entered in a specified area. The radius of that area is 200 metres. I have tried with some sample codes, but not working.

Has anyone worked with similar type of idea?

1. http://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/geofences
2. http://www.zoftino.com/android-location-proximity-alert-using-google-maps-geofencing-example
3. [GeoFence alert does not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139929/geofence-alert-does-not-show)

Comment: Probably you are missing some points. Try this link, it works like a charm, https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing

Comment: Already tried.Its not working.

Comment: Did you check error callbacks or error flags which is describing the problem?. Maybe you forgot to give location permission ?

Comment: Have u worked on the same earlier.I want to specify area of my current location.Whenever that current location is entered, the geofencer concept should work.

Comment: This is already what geofencing is. The most basic use case of it, so there is no need to explain same things as your requirement.  I suggest you cloning the repository, debug each part step by step and observe `OnCompleteListener` callback.